# convert data frame to a matrix with column 1 of df as rownames of matrix

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I have a data frame with dimensions 3695 X 20. The first column contains alphanumeric identifiers, the other 19 columns are all numeric. So, rownames(df) provides the numbers 1-3695, and colnames(df) gives the names of the columns. df[,1] provides the alphanumeric identifiers.

I would like to convert the data frame to a matrix and use column 1 of the existing data frame to be the rownames of the new matrix and maintain the column names of the data frame as the column names of the matrix.

I would also like to automate this process for use with data frames of similar but different dimensions. So, if the solution to this requires knowing the number of rows and/or columns, how can I get this information into the code without me having to look at the monitor ?

I have looked at data.matrix and reshape2 but can not seem to figure out how to do what I want.

Comment: Wait you said the first column contains identifiers, but also that `rownames(df)` identifiers. There are not the same things. `rownames()` are not stored as a column, they are stored as an attribute. So what's the case with your data? Have you simply duplicated the information. You really should add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to make it clear what your input is and what your desired output is. You can use `dim()`, `nrow()`, or `ncol()` to get the dimensions of a data.frame if that's the only question.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, rownames(df) is just a list of numbers; 1-3695.

Comment: If there is a mistake in your question, you should edit it. Again, it's not fun to answer without a reproducible example because we just end up wasting a lot of time creating one and ours may or may not actually match your data. See [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: For simplicity sake, here is a 4 X 4 simpler version of my larger data frame: structure(list(gene = c("AT1G01040", "AT1G01270", "AT1G01471", 
"AT1G01680"), log2.fold_change._Mer7_2.1_Mer7_2.2 = c(0, 0, 0, 
0), log2.fold_change._Mer7_1.2_W29_S226A_1 = c(0, 0, -1.14, 0
), log2.fold_change._Mer7_1.2_W29_1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("gene", 
"log2.fold_change._Mer7_2.1_Mer7_2.2", "log2.fold_change._Mer7_1.2_W29_S226A_1", 
"log2.fold_change._Mer7_1.2_W29_1"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With your sample data

```
X<-structure(list(gene = c("AT1G01040", "AT1G01270", "AT1G01471", "AT1G01680"), log2.fold_change._Mer7_2.1_Mer7_2.2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0), log2.fold_change._Mer7_1.2_W29_S226A_1 = c(0, 0, -1.14, 0 ), log2.fold_change._Mer7_1.2_W29_1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("gene", "log2.fold_change._Mer7_2.1_Mer7_2.2", "log2.fold_change._Mer7_1.2_W29_S226A_1", "log2.fold_change._Mer7_1.2_W29_1"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

You can write a simple helper function to create a matrix and set the right names

```
matrix.please<-function(x) {
    m<-as.matrix(x[,-1])
    rownames(m)<-x[,1]
    m
}
```

and you would use it like

```
M <- matrix.please(X)
str(M)
#  num [1:4, 1:3] 0 0 0 0 0 0 -1.14 0 0 0 ...
#  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   ..$ : chr [1:4] "AT1G01040" "AT1G01270" "AT1G01471" "AT1G01680"
#   ..$ : chr [1:3] "log2.fold_change._Mer7_2.1_Mer7_2.2"  
# "log2.fold_change._Mer7_1.2_W29_S226A_1" "log2.fold_change._Mer7_1.2_W29_1"
```

So we have a 4x3 matrix with the correct row and col names.

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse` and pipes.

```r
X<-structure(list(gene = c("AT1G01040", "AT1G01270", "AT1G01471", "AT1G01680"), log2.fold_change._Mer7_2.1_Mer7_2.2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0), log2.fold_change._Mer7_1.2_W29_S226A_1 = c(0, 0, -1.14, 0 ), log2.fold_change._Mer7_1.2_W29_1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("gene", "log2.fold_change._Mer7_2.1_Mer7_2.2", "log2.fold_change._Mer7_1.2_W29_S226A_1", "log2.fold_change._Mer7_1.2_W29_1"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

M <- X |>
  tibble::column_to_rownames(var = "gene") |>
  as.matrix() 

str(M)
#>  num [1:4, 1:3] 0 0 0 0 0 0 -1.14 0 0 0 ...
#>  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#>   ..$ : chr [1:4] "AT1G01040" "AT1G01270" "AT1G01471" "AT1G01680"
#>   ..$ : chr [1:3] "log2.fold_change._Mer7_2.1_Mer7_2.2" "log2.fold_change._Mer7_1.2_W29_S226A_1" "log2.fold_change._Mer7_1.2_W29_1"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>