# Why does R -- dplyr package return arbitrary row numbers?

Tags: r, dplyr

Take the following example from CRAN'S dplyr introduction:

```
select(flights, tail_num = tailnum)
 #> # A tibble: 336,776 x 1
 #>   tail_num
 #>      <chr>
 #> 1   N14228
 #> 2   N24211
 #> 3   N619AA
 #> 4   N804JB
 #> ... with 336,772 more rows
```

Why are these row `id`s being returned and is there anyway to remove them?

Comment: Do you mean print to the console without displaying the row numbers?

Answer (score 2):

These `id`s are only lines number that are actually not stored. They are only here for display purposes and they are not real Ids

Comment: Understood. But is there anyway to remove them

Comment: @Joseph Well, if you just want the vector... `select(flights, tail_num = tailnum) %>% c`. Otherwise maybe you want http://stackoverflow.com/a/36706785/

Comment: You should do what @Frank said to use the vector. Otherwise these values can't be removed because they don't exist anywhere in the memory, in other words there are no variables representing these values!

Comment: Won't these come up in shiny dashboard?

Comment: I don't really know I've never used it. If you really want to print your elements without the line number you can do a **for loop** and print each element individually.